# Add nodes and grouping

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, element

I'm trying to build an Xml file using XDocument and LINQ based on a file a read locally from my computer.
This seems pretty easy (and it is) until the moment i want to deal with something specific.

So, i want my code to support both this format

```
<FailReport>
  <SystemDescription>
    <SystemID>system1</SystemID>
    <ReportDate>DATE</ReportDate>
    <SpecFile>file1</SpecFile>
    <UUT>unit1</UUT>
  </SystemDescription>
  <FailDescription>
      <Test1>tst1</Test1>
      <Test2>tst2</Test2>
      <TestType>typ1</TestType>
      <Component>cmp1</Component>
      <LowerLimit>llimit</LowerLimit>
      <UpperLimit>ulimit</UpperLimit>
      <MeasuredValue>value</MeasuredValue>
    </FailDescription>
</FailReport>
```

and this format

```
<FailReport>
  <SystemDescription>
    <SystemID>system1</SystemID>
    <ReportDate>DATE</ReportDate>
    <SpecFile>file1</SpecFile>
    <UUT>unit1</UUT>
  </SystemDescription>
  <FailDescription>
      <Test1>tst1</Test1>
      <Test2>tst2</Test2>
      <TestType>typ1</TestType>
      <Component>cmp1</Component>
      <LowerLimit>llimit</LowerLimit>
      <UpperLimit>ulimit</UpperLimit>
      <MeasuredValue>value</MeasuredValue>
    </FailDescription>
    <FailDescription>
      <Test1>tst3</Test1>
      <Test2>tst4</Test2>
      <TestType>typ2</TestType>
      <Component>cmp2</Component>
      <LowerLimit>llimit3</LowerLimit>
      <UpperLimit>ulimit4</UpperLimit>
      <MeasuredValue>value1</MeasuredValue>
    </FailDescription>
</FailReport>
```

I have a function that receives the parameters like this :

```
public void newFail(string Tst1, string Tst2, string TestType, string Component, string LowerLimit, string UpperLimit, string MeasuredValue, string SystemID, string ReportDate, string SpecFile, string UUT)
```

In this function i need to do several things:

1. If the Xml doesn't exist in the location i need to create it and fill it;
2. If it exists load the file and edit it;
3. If somewhere in the Xml file already exists an entry like this "May7,2014 18:44" apply the second format ( keep the "header" that is the "SystemDescription" but add a second/third/wtv "FailDescription" block with different parameters for "Test1" , "Test2" and so on.
4. If it doesnt exist use the first format and create a "brand new block".

This is the code i have atm:

```
 void newFail(string Tst1, string Tst2, string TestType, string Component, string LowerLimit, string UpperLimit, string MeasuredValue, string SystemID, string ReportDate, string SpecFile, string UUT)
        {
               if (doesElementExist("FailReport", "SystemDescription", "ReportDate", ReportDate))       //If an element with the same Report Date exists, add it to the same parent
               {
                   ictLog.Element("FailReport").Elements("SystemDescription").Last(c => (string)c.Element("ReportDate").Value == ReportDate).Add(new XElement("FailDescription",
                                                                new XElement("Tst1", Tst1),
                                                                new XElement("Tst2", Tst2),
                                                                new XElement("TestType", TestType),
                                                                new XElement("Component", Component),
                                                                new XElement("LowerLimit", LowerLimit),
                                                                new XElement("UpperLimit", UpperLimit),
                                                                new XElement("MeasuredValue", MeasuredValue)));
                }
                else
                {                                                                                       //Otherwise add a new Parent  
                    if (!firstEntry)
                    {
                        ictLog.Element("FailReport").Add(new XElement("FailReport",
                                                                 new XElement("SystemDescription",
                                                                     new XElement("SystemID", SystemID),
                                                                     new XElement("ReportDate", ReportDate),
                                                                     new XElement("SpecFile", SpecFile),
                                                                     new XElement("UUT", UUT)),
                                                                 new XElement("FailDescription",
                                                                     new XElement("Tst1", Tst1),
                                                                     new XElement("Tst2", Tst2),
                                                                     new XElement("TestType", TestType),
                                                                     new XElement("Component", Component),
                                                                     new XElement("LowerLimit", LowerLimit),
                                                                     new XElement("UpperLimit", UpperLimit),
                                                                     new XElement("MeasuredValue", MeasuredValue))));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        firstEntry = false;

                        ictLog = new XDocument(new XElement("FailReport",
                                                                 new XElement("SystemDescription",
                                                                     new XElement("SystemID", SystemID),
                                                                     new XElement("ReportDate", ReportDate),
                                                                     new XElement("SpecFile", SpecFile),
                                                                     new XElement("UUT", UUT)),
                                                                 new XElement("FailDescription",
                                                                     new XElement("Tst1", Tst1),
                                                                     new XElement("Tst2", Tst2),
                                                                     new XElement("TestType", TestType),
                                                                     new XElement("Component", Component),
                                                                     new XElement("LowerLimit", LowerLimit),
                                                                     new XElement("UpperLimit", UpperLimit),
                                                                     new XElement("MeasuredValue", MeasuredValue))));
                    }
                }          
        }
```

And the function "doesElementExist" code is the following:

```
 public bool doesElementExist(string rootName, string parentName,string childName, string nodeValue)
        {
            if (!firstEntry)
            {
                bool value = ictLog.Elements(rootName).Elements(parentName)                                 //Get any item where the child value is the same as the specificed one (for some reason it works on reverse, returns false if found)
                      .Elements(childName)
                      .Any(x => x.Value == nodeValue);

                return value;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
```

I set the flag first entry if i don't find any file on the location that has the .xml extension.

**My problem is, the XML file generated, groups the first time as it should (uses the second format when the date parameter is the same as one already on the xml) but duplicates each entry . If i call the function a second time with a different header it creates correctly using the first format but never groups even if an entry already exists (doesn't apply the second format). Note that i have the same date but it didn't group as it should.** Example output:

```
<FailReport>
  <SystemDescription>
    <SystemID>ICTT_0030</SystemID>
    <ReportDate>May7,2014 18:44</ReportDate>
    <SpecFile>xptofile.c</SpecFile>
    <UUT>123</UUT>
    <FailDescription>
      <Tst1>tsts</Tst1>
      <Tst2>tsts1</Tst2>
      <TestType>type2</TestType>
      <Component>cTst1</Component>
      <LowerLimit>0.400</LowerLimit>
      <UpperLimit>0.800</UpperLimit>
      <MeasuredValue>O_RngV</MeasuredValue>
    </FailDescription>
    <FailDescription>
      <Tst1>tsts</Tst1>
      <Tst2>tsts1</Tst2>
      <TestType>type2</TestType>
      <Component>cTst1</Component>
      <LowerLimit>0.900</LowerLimit>
      <UpperLimit>0.700</UpperLimit>
      <MeasuredValue>0.91</MeasuredValue>
    </FailDescription>
<FailReport>
  <SystemDescription>
    <SystemID>ICTT_0030</SystemID>
    <ReportDate>May7,2014 18:44</ReportDate>
    <SpecFile>xptofile.c</SpecFile>
    <UUT>123</UUT>
    <FailDescription>
      <Tst1>tsts</Tst1>
      <Tst2>tsts1</Tst2>
      <TestType>type2</TestType>
      <Component>cTst1</Component>
      <LowerLimit>0.400</LowerLimit>
      <UpperLimit>0.800</UpperLimit>
      <MeasuredValue>O_RngV</MeasuredValue>
    </FailDescription>
    <FailDescription>
      <Tst1>tsts</Tst1>
      <Tst2>tsts1</Tst2>
      <TestType>type2</TestType>
      <Component>cTst1</Component>
      <LowerLimit>0.900</LowerLimit>
      <UpperLimit>0.700</UpperLimit>
      <MeasuredValue>0.91</MeasuredValue>
    </FailDescription>

    <SystemDescription>
      <SystemID>lalalala</SystemID>
      <ReportDate>May21,2014 11:59</ReportDate>
      <SpecFile>filefile</SpecFile>
      <UUT>111</UUT>
    </SystemDescription>
    <FailDescription>
      <Tst1>TP1300-T[201]</Tst1>
      <Tst2>Tst2002-G[1]</Tst2>
      <TestType>Res</TestType>
      <Component>R1301</Component>
      <LowerLimit>9.9000K</LowerLimit>
      <UpperLimit>13.000K</UpperLimit>
      <MeasuredValue>13.089K</MeasuredValue>
    </FailDescription>
  </FailReport>
  <FailReport>
<SystemDescription>
      <SystemID>lalalala</SystemID>
      <ReportDate>May21,2014 11:59</ReportDate>
      <SpecFile>filefile</SpecFile>
      <UUT>111</UUT>
    </SystemDescription>
     <FailDescription>
      <Tst1>tsts11111</Tst1>
      <Tst2>tssa9</Tst2>
      <TestType>Res</TestType>
      <Component>kkk</Component>
      <LowerLimit>9.9000K</LowerLimit>
      <UpperLimit>13.000K</UpperLimit>
      <MeasuredValue>13.089K</MeasuredValue>
    </FailDescription>
```

Sorry for the long post but i tried to document it as detailed as i could.

Comment: Note: I can have more than 2 entries on the second format.

Comment: My solution uses a List<FailDescription> which can handle both a single object or multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using Serialization.  See code below for writing and reading XML

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication30
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\Test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FailReport failReport = new FailReport(){
                systemDescription =  new SystemDescription(){
                        systemID = "system1",
                        reportDate = DateTime.Today,
                        specFile = "file1",
                        uut = "unit1"
                    },
                failDescriptions = new List<FailDescription>(){
                    new FailDescription{
                        test1 = "tst1",
                        test2 = "tst2",
                        testType = "typ1",
                        component = "cmp1",
                        lowerLimit = "llimit",
                        upperLimit = "ulimit",
                        measuredValue = "value"
                    },
                    new FailDescription(){
                        test1 = "tst3",
                        test2 = "tst4",
                        testType = "typ2",
                        component = "cmp2",
                        lowerLimit = "llimit3",
                        upperLimit = "ulimit4",
                        measuredValue = "value1"
                    }
                }
            };
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FailReport));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializerNamespaces _ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            _ns.Add("", "");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, failReport, _ns);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FailReport));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            FailReport newFailReport = (FailReport)xs.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("FailReport")]
    public class FailReport
    {
        [XmlElement("")]
        public SystemDescription systemDescription {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("")]
        public List<FailDescription> failDescriptions {get;set;}
    }
    [XmlRoot("SystemDescription")]
    public class SystemDescription
    {
        [XmlElement("")]
        public string systemID {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("")]
        public DateTime  reportDate {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("")]
        public string specFile {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("")]
        public string uut {get;set;}

    }
    [XmlRoot("FailDescription")]
    public class FailDescription
    {
        [XmlElement("Test1")]
        public string test1 {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("Test2")]
        public string test2 {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("TestType")]
        public string testType {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("Component")]
        public string component {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("LowerLimit")]
        public string lowerLimit {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("UpperLimit")]
        public string upperLimit {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("MeasuredValue")]
        public string measuredValue {get;set;}
    }
}
```